# Protractor element not clickable at some point? But same element receiving its click event?

Tags: angularjs, testing, protractor

I am doing end to end testing using protractor. I am getting an error like

```
Failed: unknown error: Element 
<button type="button" ng-click="onGPlusBtnPress()" class="btn btn-lg 
btn-google btn-block">...</button> 
is not clickable at point (919, 241). Other element would receive 
the click: 
<button type="button" ng-click="onGPlusBtnPress()" class="btn btn-lg 
btn-google btn-block">...</button>
```

It seems that the error is telling that same element is receiving click event, then why it is not working. there are no other clickable elements overlapping on it.

What should be done to resolve the problem?

[see web page design here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCReq.png)

Comment: Can you share the link and html code. Also the code which you tried.

Answer (score -1):

Try by adding window size in your config file.

```
onPrepare: function() {
  browser.manage().window().setSize(1600, 800);
}
```

if it still doesn't work try it.

```
browser.actions().mouseMove(element).click();
```

Comment: I got it, actually i have two buttons with same config at same location one for google login and other for google signup. So by default i was accessing 1st button. Accessing 2nd just fixes the problem.

Comment: yes, generally protractor gives you the right error message. You should debug to that step and check what's wrong.